# What is the best way to maintain and update offline changes between an IOS client and a server?

Tags: database, grails, restkit

I have implemented an ios app that uses restkit with coredata and a grails backend with SQL. I got the "get" and "post" part working as long as there is network connectivity and as long as the server is up and running.

I am using an ID assigned by the server as a primary key in the core data to sync the objects. If I allow the users to create or update the objects when they are offline or when server has issues, what would be the best way to maintain the state and update the server at a later point in time? I would like to know what would be the best practices in this regard.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I've tackled this in a couple ways, though it's not a simple task.

In the first, I added an NSAttribute to all of my Core Data models to track their state (i.e. whether they should be sent with a POST or PUT request to the server). Then I monitored the reachability notifications (RestKit exposes these via `RKReachabilityObserver`) and sent the objects that had been modified with the appropriate method to the server. The code I used for this can be found [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/197/files) (but is outdated and shouldn't be used directly).

The second, very recent, method that I've devised is to create a Core Data entity that is essentially a queue, and changes in the model are registered in the queue, and synced with the server when the network is available. It's open for discussion on github as of this writing, and is NOT very thoroughly tested at this point, but [here it is](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/573).